# Trouble installing GAPlugin with plugman

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I have downloaded and installed PhoneGap 3.0.

I have installed plugman and have verified that the 'plugman' command is valid.

I have created a project from the command line with phonegap.

I have downloaded and unzipped the GAPlugin repo from github

I use the following command to install the plugin in my project:

```
C:\Users\JRea\workspace\GAPluginTest>plugman --platform android --project
C:\Users\JRea\workspace\GAPluginTest --plugin C:\Users\JRea\GAPlugin-master
```

When running this command plugman just spits out its reference information.  I don't get any confirmation that the plugin has been installed.  When I run:

```
$ plugman search
```

...I don't get any results related to GAPlugin. Does anyone have any guidance on this?  The documentation for plugman and GAPlugin is pretty slack in my opinion, and I have exhausted all of my resources.  This doesn't really sound that complicated, and surely people have gotten it to work successfully. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that doing this is much easier with Phonegap build. Just include:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin" />
```

in your config.xml.  Then, include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="GAPlugin.js"></script>
```

in your index.html.  This include happens after you include phonegap.js though obviously.  The sample index and css file on the [github](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin) works just fine with this method. And you'll have to change the tracking id in the sample code to match the one for your G.A. account.

There is a lot of reading material on the internet that says G.A. with Phonegap requires your G.A. account to be configured as a website. I was able to get the github sample code to work with my G.A. account configured as a mobile app.  Apparently, Google may have rolled out an update that addresses this issue.

Answer (score -2):

As of this writing, the GAPlugin is only supported in Phonegap version 2.9 and below.

Comment: I installed Phonegap 2.8 using: npm install phonegap@2.8 -g.  Then I ran the same command for plugman and I still don't see GAPlugin getting installed.

Comment: Edited post to reflect "as of this writing" because some tool downvoted based on old info...